# Using both 1.1 and 2.0 frameworks on Windows 2003 x64

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2003

So, much to my annoyance I discover (after lots of research), that when running 1.1 and 2.0 dot.net frameworks on a 64bit 2003 install, it removes the asp.net tab from the IIS properties.  I've tried the registry hacks, I've tried registering 32bit versions of both frameworks, and no luck.  My only work around is running the excellent [ASP.NET switcher](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/ASPNETVersionSwitcher.aspx) from Dennis Bauer.

Does anyone else have any insight?

Comment: What was your installation order? I am logged into a x64 box with 1.1 and 2.0 right now, and he has an ASP.NET tab in IIS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you might try running the 32-bit version of MMC.  IIRC, MMC can only load extensions that are the same bit-ness as itself, and the .Net 2.0 extension is 32-bit only.

That said, the tool you linked in your question is very useful for working around this issue as well.